# AttributeError: type object 'HTML' has no attribute 'Table'

Tags: python, html, attributeerror

This is my code snippet and am getting the following error:
python version 2.7.10

```
from html import HTML
t = HTML.Table()
colored_cell1 = HTML.TableCell('Status', bgcolor='lime')
```

Comment: could you tell us what you are trying to do?

Comment: Is this [tag:python-2.x]?